# How to use keyring instead of plain text passwords in a config file (Mopidy)

Tags: python, passwords, keychain, gnome-keyring, mopidy

I just installed *keyring* on macOS. I'd like to leverage this instead of keeping Spotify's username and password for [Mopidy](https://Mopidy.com/) in my *mopidy.conf*.

Everything works well, and I can read my Spotify password from the Keychain by running:

```
python -m keyring get spotify 0000000000
```

After reading [here](https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-gmusic/issues/172), and [here](https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-spotify/pull/65), my understanding is that I need to leave the *mopidy.conf* credentials empty:

```
username =
password =
```

and then setup the keyring config located at *(~/.local/share/python_keyring)*.

Is it possible to still use the macOS Keychain? If not, how to properly setup the keyring config file?